# Does ${d \over dt} \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(x,t) dt$ = $ f(x, v(x)) - f(x, u(x)) $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

My thought)

By the Leibniz rule and  the function $u(x), v(x)$ are constant for the variable, $t$

Hence,

${d \over dt} \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(x,t) dt$ = $\int_{u(x)} ^ {v(x)} f_t(x,t) dt $ = $ f(x, v(x)) - f(x, u(x)) $

(Here the $f_t(x,t) = {d \over dt} f(x,t)$)

So my answer is true.

But, I couldn't my answer is true or not. If my answer is correct, How could I prove that?  If not true, Which point do I have a mistake?

Any advice would be thanksful.

Comment: No. That integral is not a function of $t$ anymore.

Comment: Your integral is a function of $x$ and ideally you should apply $d/dx$ on it. In that case you will have an additional term $\int_{u} ^{v} \frac{\partial} {\partial x} f(x, t) \, dt$ also.